# Command to see the size of Harddrive in Debian?

Tags: debian

It is perhaps `/proc` or something else. So how can I for sure know which harddrive I am using Debian?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think `fdisk` or `df` should do for you.

```
$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 128.0 GB, 128035676160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15566 cylinders, total 250069680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x76e7062a

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    70383615    35190784    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2   *   249434112   250048511      307200    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        70385662   249432063    89523201    5  Extended
/dev/sda5        70385664    71383039      498688   83  Linux
/dev/sda6        71385088    73383935      999424   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda7        73385984   249432063    88023040   83  Linux


$ df -h #working on Debian
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7        84G   75G  5.6G  94% /
udev            1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           768M  944K  767M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.9G  364K  1.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda5       484M   47M  413M  11% /boot
```